# Can False Swipe cause wobbling?

Tags: pokemon-rumble-world

According to [Serebii](http://serebii.net/rumbleworld/mechanics.shtml):

> False Swipe is a handy move as it will never knock out a Pokémon, but if you keep hitting it with False Swipe, then it will likely wobble.

But I'm seeing a lot of people saying that this is not true, e.g. [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/141816-pokemon-rumble-world/71611900). I've tried it with my *Gutsy Spearow* and I've never wobbled a pokemon in this way.

Can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *False Swipe* cannot wobble an enemy when reduced to 1HP. You actually have to deal damage to make it wobble, because it happens when you inflict a critical hit.

Morover, Serebii has removed that statement.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm exactly, but I would say it should cause wobbling since False Swipe can do damage but not faint a pokemon, meaning that you have plenty of chances to make it wobble.  Hope this helped

Comment: But if the Pokemon already has 1 hp False Swipe won't do damage anymore. Rephrasing my question: does I actually need to inflict damage to wobble a Pokemon?